# Allow longer file names on ESP32 SPIFFS

Tags: esp32, spiffs

I have a nodemcu-32s microcontroller on which I have setup a simple webserver that serves a spiffs directory. The project uses platformio to upload to the ESP32.

I am trying to serve a react app from my esp but some of the filenames of the react app build directory are too long for SPIFFS, which is limited to 32 characters.

So I was wondering, is there a way to increase this character limit? So that my react app will fit on it?